# How do I get data from associated models in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, comments, cakephp-1.3

I create a simple blog with cakephp where i have some posts and some comments.
After i bake an application it create a `comments` folder with the `index.ctp` and a `posts` folder with `the index.ctp`

What i want to do is display them as fallow:

```
Post1
  comment1
  comment2
Post2
  comment1
  comment2
```

If i place the comments inside the posts/index.ctp i get an error telling me that the `$comments` is not defined.

How can i do this?
Thanks

edit:
alright, im sorry for the comeback, but it's still a bit unclear. I do have the `$hasMany` relationship setup, in fact on the page that displays the posts i have a link that points me to the comments. The only thing that i want them to be displayed in the same page as the posts.

i should be able to say `<?php echo $comment['Comment']['content']; ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your controllers.

If you want to display Comment information in a Posts view, you need to be sure that the Posts controller can load the data.

The "CakePHP" way is to define relationships between models.  Check your baked models and see if there is something like this:

```
class Post extends AppModel{

var $hasMany = array( 'Comment' );

}
```

When the models are associated with each other, your Posts controller will automatically find Post objects and their associated Comment objects.

For instance, this line:

```
$this->Post->findById( $id );
```

Will produce something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
    (
        [id] => 42
        [text] => Post1
    )

    [Comment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_id] => 42
            [text] => Comment1
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_id] => 42
            [text] => Comment2
        )
    )
)
```

Good documentation at http://book.cakephp.org/

- [Model Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together)
- [Retreiving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data)

*EDIT: Adding more info after your comment*

As long as the models have the association, CakePHP will pull the data appropriately (unless you set `Recursive => false` or are using [`Containable`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) which I assume you aren't).

Check your PostsController controller and see how it's loading the data.  I'm guessing it is doing something like the following:

```
$post = $this->Post->findById( $id );
$this->set( compact( 'post' ) );
```

or

```
$this->data = $this->Post->findById( $id );
```

Check which way it is storing the retrieved data, and then access that variable from the view.

For example, if it is storing the data in a variable named "$post", you would put something like this in your view:

```
// output the 'text' field of the 'post' object
echo $post[ 'post' ][ 'text' ];  

// loop through associated comments
foreach ( $post[ 'comment' ] as $comment ){  

    //output the 'text' field of a 'comment' object
    echo $comment[ 'text' ];  

}
```

By default CakePHP stashes tons of detail in arrays after retrieving data.  The trick is to know the hierarchy of the data and fetch it from the array accordingly.

Comment: a bit more info is always appreciated.. maybe an example?  thanks

Comment: alright, im sorry for the comeback, but it's still a bit unclear. I do have the `$hasMany` relationship setup, in fact on the page that displays the posts i have a link that points me to the comments. The only thing that i want them to be displayed in the same page as the posts

Comment: @Patrioticcow Added examples.  I'm sure CakePHP is already pulling the data you want.  You just have to retrieve it from the array.  Try putting `<? echo debug( pr( $VariableHoldingPostInfo ) ); ?>` in your view and see what the data structure looks like.

Comment: @Patrioticcow Further to previous comment.  My examples in the answer were written to display 1 post with associated comments simply for brevity.  The concept is the same to iterate through an array of Posts.